# Azure WebApps Deploy with Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy, azure-webapps

I'm ripping my hair trying to publish a .Net app to Azure WebApps using Jenkins. Following [this guide](http://www.swtestacademy.com/azure-appservices-with-jenkins/), I get stuck with the following error:

```
P:\Scripts\Azure\PublishProfiles\my.PublishSettings(1,1): error MSB4068: The element <publishData> is unrecognized, or not supported in this context. [c:\jenkins-slave\workspace\msbuildtest\my\my.csproj]
```

I have downloaded `my.PublishSettings` from Azure and it looks like

```
<publishData>
    <publishProfile
            profileName="my - Web Deploy"
            publishMethod="MSDeploy"
            publishUrl="my.scm.azurewebsites.net:443"
            msdeploySite="my"
            userName="$my"
            userPWD="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            destinationAppUrl="http://my.azurewebsites.net"
            SQLServerDBConnectionString=""
            mySQLDBConnectionString=""
            hostingProviderForumLink=""
            controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com"
            webSystem="WebSites">
        <databases />
    </publishProfile>
    <publishProfile
            profileName="my - FTP"
            publishMethod="FTP"
            publishUrl="ftp://waws-prod-am2-045.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot"
            ftpPassiveMode="True"
            userName="my\$my"
            userPWD="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            destinationAppUrl="http://my.azurewebsites.net"
            SQLServerDBConnectionString=""
            mySQLDBConnectionString=""
            hostingProviderForumLink=""
            controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com"
            webSystem="WebSites">
        <databases />
    </publishProfile>
</publishData>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you  please provide the msbuild command parameters

Comment: @Karthikeyan (Un)fortunately, we have switched from Azure to AWS because of this (and other problems to which we didn't get any answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this may not help you now that you have moved to AWS but there is a new plugin for deploying to Azure Web App: https://aka.ms/azapp-service.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.